# Getting PAGELATCH_UP:tempdb:1(PFS) with so many waiting queue

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, configuration, tempdb

Getting `PAGELATCH_UP:tempdb:1(PFS)` with so many waiting queue. What can be solution?

We have two hexacore processors. Ideally how much tempdb can we create to handle this issue?

Answer (score 3):

Kendra Little writes in [How to Tell if You Need More Tempdb Files](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2014/05/tell-need-tempdb-files/):

> First of all, if you just have one tempdb file, consider adding more files as preventive medicine. Don’t go crazy with this. The formula [recommended by Microsoft in KB 2154845](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2154845/recommendations-to-reduce-allocation-contention-in-sql-server-tempdb-d) to use one tempdb data file for each logical processor up to 8 processors is a good place to start.

and:

> Remember: this only applies to tempdb data files. You only need one tempdb log file.
>
> Also remember that the tempdb data files will be used proportionally with their size. This means that you should keep the files equally sized.

Read the full article to learn more.